# access textfield values from java script in php

Tags: php, javascript

function addRow(tableID) {

```
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "text";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "File";
        cell2.appendChild(element2);
        //cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

}
```

How to access the values added in the text boxes in php from here?

Please advise.

Comment: You need to make an AJAX request to your server and tell it the current values of the input elements. Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Javascript is on the client and PHP on the server you are going to have to submit these values to the server via a form.